# How to Use .fadeIn() with .after() Function

Tags: jquery

Can you Please let me know why I cant use the `.fadeIn()` function at this code properly? What I would like to do is mixing the `.after()` and `.fadeIn()` together.

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  $(this).after('<div class="err">There is an Error</div>').fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after()` returns the original element, in your case the input. You can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HqhJ3/

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  $(this).after('<div class="err">There is an Error</div>').next('.err').fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

Or instead use `insertAfter()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/HaV7H/

```
$("input").blur(function(){
  $('<div class="err">There is an Error</div>').insertAfter(this).fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

Note that I also had to set the `.err` div to `display:none;` initially.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to `.fadeIn()` the `<div class="err">`:

The issue is that `.after()` will return the collection it was called on rather than a collection of the arguments. So, the statement is currently attempting to `.fadeIn()` the `<input>` instead.

For this, you can swap the elements' places and instead use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$('<div class="err">There is an Error</div>').insertAfter(this)...
```

---

Also note that to `.fadeIn()` any element requires that it's currently hidden -- either with CSS or `.hide()`:

```
.err {
    display: none;
}
```

```
$(...).hide().fadeIn("slow");
```